# How can I submit boolean value with a checkbox in form in Jade?

Tags: checkbox, pug

I am using Jade for templates in NodeJS.

I want to send values of a checkbox.

```
            input#isNewProduct.checkbox(type='checkbox', name="isNewProduct", checked=product.isNewProduct)
```

But it always sends true in form.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
checked=(product.isNewProduct || undefined)
```

Comment: Thank you. And in the controller, I wrote if(!req.body["isNewProduct"]){
    product.isNewProduct = false;
  } now I can get the value.